# Relative seek times for various types of storage media

Tags: performance, storage, memory, ssd

Does anyone know the approximate time required to retrieve and modify a kilobyte of data for various types of storage media in a typical modern server?

Specifically:

- RAM
- Hard disk
- SSD

This would be a random access, not sequential.

I'm more interested in the orders of magnitude than the specific actual numbers (since I don't know the actual hardware my software will be running on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well generally speaking you get the roughly the following speeds for random reads;

- Main Memory (DDR3 1600) - 12GBps
- Fast Disk (6Gb SAS 2.5 15k) - 5-15MBps
- Slow Disk (3Gb SATA 3.5 7.2) - 2-10Mbps
- Average SSD (Intel X25) - 50MBps

Hopefully that should give you some ideas on magnitude.